# swift: cannot assign value of type UIView to type CGRect

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, xcode7

In the `for` loop I am trying to place images from `arrayOfImages` in rectangles that I've created with `CGRect`.

But after that I want to use class `MyClassView` which inherits `UIView`, because I have there additional functions that I want to apply on my rectangle images that I've just created, but I am getting the error

```
cannot assign value of type UIView to type CGRect
```

```swift
let widthRect = 50

func createMyRects(){

    let insetSize = CGRectInset(self.view.bounds, CGFloat(Int(widthRect)), CGFloat(Int(widthRect))).size

    for i in 0...arrayOfImages.count-1{

        let pointX = CGFloat(UInt(arc4random() % UInt32(UInt(insetSize.width))))
        let pointY = CGFloat(UInt(arc4random() % UInt32(UInt(insetSize.height))))
        let showImages = UIImageView(image: arrayOfImages[i])
        let newFrame = CGRect(x: pointX, y: pointY, width: CGFloat(widthRect), height: CGFloat(widthRect))
        //showImages.frame = newFrame

        let newFrame2 = MyClassView(frame: newFrame)

        showImages.frame = newFrame2  //here it says: cannot assign value of type UIView view to type CGRect 
        view.addSubview(showImages)

    }
}
```

Comment: Actually the error message says: `error: cannot assign value of type 'MyClassView' to type 'CGRect'`

Answer (score 1):

To fix the error you need to assign the frame of your UIView subclass to the frame.

```
showImages.frame = newFrame2.frame
```

Your variable names are a bit misleading.

Comment: Thanks for answering, i tried that in the meanwhile, adding .frame, but still haven't got what i wanted. In class MyClassView which inherits UIView there are some extra features such as pan move, getting random color and bringing objects in front, that are clicked on. So, for practice, i want to assign those features of MyClass to new Rects that i've created, except getting random color, i want to fill Rects with images from arrayOfImages. If i may be boring just a little bit more and get your opinion on this, it would be great. Thanks for the first reply and hope to get another info from you.

Answer (score 0):

Justin gave an answer that would let your code compile, but it still doesn't make sense. I assume that the `MyClassView(frame: newFrame)` bit is an intializer for a `MyClassView` object? Why in the world would you create a new view object only to take it's frame and assign it to another view, and then discard the newly created view?

Why do you need to create a `MyClassView` object at all? My guess is that you don't, and that you shouldn't. Get rid of the line that creates a `MyClassView` object entirely and just use the code you have commented out? (`showImages.frame = newFrame`).

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried what Justin said, adding .frame, but still haven't got what i wanted. Since I am new to Swift, i want, just for practice, to assign features of MyClassView to newly created Rects, except getting random color from MyClassView. Instead of getting random color from MyClass i want to fill Rects with images from arrayOfImages, that's why i made second frame. In class MyClassView which inherits UIView there are some extra features such as pan move, getting random color and bringing objects in front, that are clicked on. It would be excellent if could get help on that.

Comment: "i want, just for practice, to assign features of MyClassView to newly created Rects." That makes no sense. A rect has exactly 4 properties: x,y,width, and height. Same for "... i want to fill Rects with images from arrayOfImages..." You don't fill a CGRect with anything. A CGRect is a set of coordinates. A view object has a frame property which tells it where it is located in it's superview. You need to stop and read up on Cocoa fundamentals. You are hopelessly confused and I'm not going to un-confuse you with a few forum posts. Only study on your part will do that.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood me, maybe i didn't write it right. I will ask you for help once more, sorry for the trouble. Image can be placed in rect, or whatever the word is - put it in rect, add it in the rect.  My problem is not about rectangles, it is about assigning my class to the rectangles that i've created, so i can pan rectangles (and use their last location) but i don't want rects to have color that my class is giving to them, i want images from array in them. If you can help this is what my class looks like:

Comment: I think it is one or two lines of code. If it's not, i am starting with reading and un-confusing myself :)

Comment: You think *what* is one or two lines of code? You code is VERY confused. It's possible that it is the language barrier, but I think not. Where are the rects that you are trying to assign to? Where/how are they defined? What type is showImages? I can't make out the git links you posted because all the variable names and comments are in a different language (Dutch?).

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've solved it. Just wanted to post the answer if someone else comes up with same problem. Previously i tried to assign images, which i made from one picture with function that sliced original picture, to bunch of rectangles that i created. But it didn't work because i didn't correctly make my class MojView. It inherited UIView, now it inherits UIImageView. Besides, i made a change in one line of code and the result is - rectangles are assigned with images and all of them can be dragged which was my intention when i created MojClass. Here is the code for both MojClass and the rest of app. MojClass: https://github.com/Vukovi/Ne-to/blob/master/README.md && Rest: https://github.com/Vukovi/ostatak/blob/master/README.md